# Controller not working inside another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a div in which i am adding a directive(Filtertest).`<div fitlertest></div>`
which is inside a controller ctrl1. The directive have a template. And template is having another controller "classFilterCtrl".

```
 angular.module("class-filter.tpl.html", []).run(function($templateCache) {
             $templateCache.put("class-filter.tpl.html", < div id = "filterpop"
                 ng - controller = "classFilterCtrl" >
                 < a class = "close-icon"
                 ng - click = "closeReport()" > < /a> < button ng - click = "classFilterPop()" > Show Filter < /button>");
             }).directive('fitlertest', function() {
             return {
                 restrict: 'AE',
                 replace: true,
                 templateUrl: 'class-filter.tpl.html'
             };
         });
```

Now when i am calling classFilterPop() from template. it's not working.
here is the controller..

```
.controller('classFilterCtrl', function($scope) {
console.log('here')
$scope.classFilterPop = function() {
    var html = $compile('<div id="classFilter" class="panel-report-js"><div class="reports-popup" style = "position: absolute;top:53px !important;left:-60px !important; background:#FFF;"><div ng-include="../admin/common/jasper-reporting/context-handlers/class-tab/class-filter-popup.tpl.html" >Some Text</div></div></div>')($scope);
    console.log(html)
    angular.element('#menu-container').append(html);
}
scope.closeReport = function() {
    console.log("close clicked")
    angular.element('.panel-report-js').remove();
}

})
```

Comment: That's the exact code you are using for `$templateCache.put`? Open the debug console, you'll see an error message.

Comment: you appear to have some syntax errors..  $scope.closeReport
You need to inject $compile into your controller
In your $templateCache.put, I believe you need to wrap your template html in quotes.
Clean that up first, then see if it works.

Comment: scope.closeReport = function() <-- you are not using $scope. <-- change this too

Comment: @sergiu some changes to make make the code small here. BTW i don't have any error

Comment: @tpie in $scope.classFilterPop is not even triggering i have consoled it

Comment: can you set up a plunker?  It's hard to diagnose the problem when there appears to be syntax errors.  scope.closeReport SHOULD throw an error.

If you have a syntax error anywhere in your controller it's going to cause problems for the whole thing.

Comment: @tpie scope i have changed to $scope. that's not a problem. $scope.classFilterPop is not triggering. BTW i'll try to put it in plunker. actually the file is a GRUNT file, so its bit hard to but it in plunker. but i'll try

Comment: Seems working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/fmm4wwpv/)